# How to build DockerImage from Spring Boot jar

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot

I am trying to build a Docker Image from a simple Spring RESTful web service jar.

For that I have specified the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I am trying to "Build a Docker Image with Maven" from my IDEA cli like stated in the instructions [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)

```
./mvnw install dockerfile:build
```

Unfortunately this throws an exception:

```
Could not build image: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
```

Since I don't know how to solve this I tried to build an image from the terminal with `docker` command:

```
$ docker build nordic/demo
```

Which created the image but with name and tag as `<none>`. Read about it from docker [documentations](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with--) but nothing said about that.

I am new to Docker so im sure there is some fundamental misunderstanding in how to build the Docker Image. Mainly:

1. When building from terminal how does Docker know how to name the Image?
2. When building with spotify plugin, why/what permissions are required to use the plugin (logging in to dockerhub before the build didn't help)?

Thanks for any pointers or explanations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[spring boot docker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)

this link will be helpful to build your docker image with spring boot.

```
<properties>
   <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
    <buildArgs>
        <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
    </buildArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

this plugin you to include in your pom, you can change you image name in properties field.

if you are getting permission denied error, you have to run it with **sudo** command

Answer (score 1):

Set the permission in /var/run/docker for your_own_username instead of root using the below example command, then give a try.

sudo chown -R root:your_own_username /var/run/docker

Answer (score 0):

When you run command:

```
docker build -t demo:1 .
```

in string 'demo:1' demo is `repository` name and string after colon '1' is `tag` of image and dot (.) in the end means current directory is `build context` where your `Dockerfile` is residing.

A repository can have many images and they are uniquely identified by tag. If you run command like this without providing tag:

```
docker build -t demo .
```

docker will create new image in demo repository and by default attach tag named 'latest' with image, so image in this case will be demo:latest. And repository demo will have 2 images demo:1 and demo:latest. Also tag 'latest' does not mean image is latest it is just name of tag.